# Rails route not working using cucumber to test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, controllers

[Hello this is my first question on Stackoverflow so please bear with me, I will try to give as much detail as possible. I am new to coding and currently working on a rails app, I am building a discussion board. I have built my user model and discussion model thus far, where discussion belongs_to user and user has_many discussions. My test is failing on line 10 the link for New Discussion seems to be set to the right route and when I pry into it it's showing the correct path.Then on line 15 the current path is on the index page...so I'm not sure if my test is poorly written or if I've missed something. I hope this along with the screenshots is enough info...I have literally spent a day on this and I'm at my wits end...any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejU7r.png)
[rails routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcsJe.png)

My Tests*

```
# A user starts a new discussion
Given("they click on the discussion link") do
click_link 'DISCUSSIONS'
end

Then("they will be redirected to the discussions index page") do
expect(current_path).to eq(user_discussions_path(@user.id))
end

   When("they click on the new discussion link") do
   click_link 'New Discussion'
   end

  Then("they will be redirected to the new discussion page") do
  expect(current_path).to eq(new_user_discussion_path(@user.id))
  end
```

Discussion Index Page*

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
   <%= render 'discussions_navbar' %>
   <%= link_to "New Discussion", new_user_discussion_path %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Binding Pry on current_path from test*

```
[1] pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)> current_path
=> "/users/1715/discussions"
[2] pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)> new_user_discussion_path(@user.id)
=> "/users/1715/discussions/new"
[3] pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)> expect(current_path).to 
eq(new_user_discussion_path(@user.id))
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError:
expected: "/users/1715/discussions/new"
got: "/users/1715/discussions"
```

Binding pry on New Discussion Link*

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fd3a62cf660>>)> new_user_discussion_path
=> "/users/1722/discussions/new"
```

Error Message*

```
When they click on the new discussion link                 # features/step_definitions/discussion_steps.rb:10
      undefined method `discussions_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd3a62cf660>:0x007fd3a6681740> (ActionView::Template::Error)
      ./app/views/discussions/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_discussions__form_html_erb__787511772381390310_70273503263920'
      ./app/views/discussions/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_discussions_new_html_erb___371545055918840709_70273503334040'
      ./features/step_definitions/discussion_steps.rb:11:in `"they click on the new discussion link"'
      features/discussion.feature:10:in `When they click on the new discussion link'
```

Form for New Discussion*

```
<%= simple_form_for @discussion do |d| %>
  <%= d.input :title, label: "Discussion Title" %>
  <%= d.input :description %>
  <%= d.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Routes*

user_discussions 
GET       /users/:user_id/discussions(.:format)                             discussions#index

POST      /users/:user_id/discussions(.:format)                             discussions#create
       new_user_discussion 
GET       /users/:user_id/discussions/new(.:format)                         discussions#new

Comment: It seems really straight forward - `new_user_discussion_path` requires a `user_id` param. You have not provided it in your index page view.

Comment: I tried that already and the user id is within scope from the path...see my binding.pry...    1: <div class="container">
    2:   <div class="grid">
    3:     <%= render 'discussions_navbar' %>
    4: <% binding.pry %>
 => 5:     <%= link_to "New Discussion", new_user_discussion_path %>
    6:
    7:   </div>
    8: </div>

[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fa0c6075df0>>)> new_user_discussion_path
=> "/users/1750/discussions/new"
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fa0c6075df0>>)>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`<%= simple_form_for [current_user, @discussion] do |d| %>`

Comment: Thank you that worked...I used the instance variable @current_user and it worked thank you!!

Comment: one more question...so it seems to be saving to my discussions table but now I can't get it to display...this is what I get from the server...Processing by DiscussionsController#create as HTML
 "discussion"=>{"title"=>"test", "description"=>"test123"}, "commit"=>"Save", "user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (11.6ms)  INSERT INTO "discussions" ("title", "description", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id" ..but there is no discussion id?

Comment: That is just an echo of the SQL that is going on in the server. When you click the create button it should be taking you back to the index page, does it not?

Comment: If you mean that now your discussion doesn't display anywhere, I don't see anywhere in your code above where it would - in your index page you have a navbar and a link to the form for create/edit, but you don't display any information about the existing discussions